# Google My Maps integrated on own site

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api

The My Maps solution from Google is great, especially for quick adding layers and styling. Is it possible to export the map to my own website  as a full sized map and without the My Maps logo? There´s the embed solution but that´s not what I´m looking for. In Fusion Tables this is easy, when complete html code is generated. I imagine that i have to integrate my API key as well.